# Calling a Facebook batch call using Appcelerator Module.Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I spend about 2 hrs looking to do a batch call using Appcelerator Module.Facebook. I needed to get the Profile name and Picture. And I thought I wanted to do this in one HTTP request instead of two.

After a deep dive i finally found a way to do. I will post my answer in the answer section below.

Incase anyone else comes up against this..

Answer (score 0):

```
var fb = require('facebook');
var log = require("log");


...

// After logging in 


// gets user profile image and name uses a batch method example
    function getUserInfo(userId) {

        var batch = 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/picture"}]&access_token=' + fb.getAccessToken();

        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com?" + batch;
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            // function called when the response data is available
            onload : function(e) {
                log.args(this.responseText);              

            },
            // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
            onerror : function(e) {
                log.args(e.error);
            },
            timeout : 5000 // in milliseconds
        });

        // Prepare the connection.
        client.open("POST", url);
        // Send the request.
        client.send();
    }
```

This is how you would do a batch call using AppC, however there is a better way to get the info that i needed. In my case I only needed the Facebook name and picture

```
function getGraphPath(userId) {
        fb.requestWithGraphPath('me?fields=id,name,picture', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
                log.args('Modules.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath', JSON.parse(e.result));
            } else if (e.error) {
                log.args(e.error);
            } else {
                log.args('Unknown response');
            }
        });
    }
```